# python ssh stdout multiple

Tags: python, ssh, stdout

In python, I am trying to connect thru ssh and play multiple commands one by one.
This code works fine and output is printed out to my screen:

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-t', '-t', 'user@host']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('pwd\n')
p.stdin.write('ls -l\n') 
p.stdin.write('exit\n')   
p.stdin.close()
```

My problem is when I try to grab each response in a string. I have tried this but the read function is blocking:

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-t', '-t', 'user@host']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('pwd\n')
st1 = p.stdout.read()
p.stdin.write('ls -l\n')    
st2 = p.stdout.read()
p.stdin.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read()` call is blocking because, when called with no argument, `read()` will read from the stream in question until it encounters `EOF`.

If your use case is as simple as your example code, a cheap workaround is to defer reading from `p.stdout` until after you close the connection:

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-t', '-t', 'deploy@pdb0']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('pwd\n')
p.stdin.write('ls -l\n')
p.stdin.write('exit\n')    
p.stdin.close()
outstr = p.stdout.read()
```

You'll then have to parse `outstr` to separate the output of the different comamnds. (Looking for occurrences of the remote shell prompt is probably the most straightforward way to do that.)

If you need to read the complete output of one command before sending another, you have several problems.  First this can block:

```
p.stdin.write('pwd\n')
st1 = p.stdout.read()
```

because the command you write to `p.stdin` might be buffered.  You need to flush the command before looking for output:

```
p.stdin.write('pwd\n')
p.stdin.flush()
st1 = p.stdout.read()
```

The `read()` call will still block, though.   What you want to do is call `read()` with a specified buffer size and read the output in chunks until you encounter the remote shell prompt again.  But even then you'll still need to use `select` to check the status of `p.stdout` to make sure you don't block.

There's a library called [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net) that implements that logic for you.  It'll be much easier to use that (or, even better, `pxssh`, which specializes `pexpect` for use over ssh connections), as getting everything right is rather hairy, and different OSes behave somewhat differently in edge cases. (Take a look at `pexpect.spawn.read_nonblocking()` for an example of how messy it can be.)

Even cleaner, though, would be to use [paramiko](http://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), which provides a higher level abstraction to doing things over ssh connections.  In particular, look at the example usage of the [paramiko.client.SSHClient](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.13/api/client.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alp that it's probably easier to have a library to do the connection logic for you. pexpect is one way to go. The below is an example with paramiko. http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.13/

```
import paramiko

host = 'myhost'
port, user, password = '22', 'myuser', 'mypass'
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(host, port, user, password, timeout=10)

command = 'ls -l'
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
errors = stderr.read()
output = stdout.read()
client.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for both of you for your answers. To keep it simple I have updated my code with:

```
def getAnswer(p, cmnd):
    # send my command
    if len(cmnd) > 0:
        p.stdin.write(cmnd + '\n')
        p.stdin.flush()
    # get reply -- until prompt received
    st = ""
    while True:
        char = p.stdout.read(1)
        st += char
        if char == '>':
            return st

cmd = ['ssh', '-t', '-t', 'user@host']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#discard welcome message
getAnswer(p, '')
st1 = getAnswer(p, 'pwd')
st2 = getAnswer(p, 'ls -l')
...
p.stdin.write('exit\n')
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()
```

This is not perfect but works fine. To detect a prompt I am simply waiting for a '>' this could be improved by first sending a 'echo $PS1' and build a regexp accordingly.